# Should I keep primary keys in my denormalized views (snowflake)?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am planning to build some wide tables in snowflake. The underlying data is highly normalized, so there is a lot of joining involved.

To illustratate the point, consider TRANSACTIONS (1b records), PRODUCTS (10k records) and PRODUCT_CATEGORY (50 records)

I would look to build:

```
# Creating a view in snowflake
SELECT t.*, p.productName, pc.productCategoryName 
FROM TRANSACTIONS t 
JOIN PPRODUCTS p ON p.product_id = t.product_id
JOIN PRODUCT_CATEGORY pc ON pc.product_category_id = p.product_category_id
```

My question is whether I should keep `product_category_id` or `product_id` in the view? In theory it should be quicker to query based on the (integer) Id rather than on the (string) `productName` or `productCategoryName`.

That said, I may be overthinking this. I'm new to snowflake so not 100% sure how much of this is important.

Comment: By "keep `product_category_id` or `product_id` in the view" do you mean projecting them as columns in the select? It won't matter much. It will return more data to the client if they use select *, so if it's not helpful to have them in the result set that should be considered. You may want to considerer denormalizing to the strings though. Storage is cheap. Joining on every query takes longer than joining once in a transformation step.

Comment: But if you are meaning, "later other things will join to this massive table" then yes keeping the id's will give better equality joins over the strings, just because they are "better" but also they are more accurately represented in the meta data used to prune. Aka just include it, it's practically free. And nobody should be doing `select *` so let those people worry about the perf of doing things they shouldn't be doing.

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood, you have both a natural key (the actual value that has semantic meaning to a user - like a unique product SKU or name), and a surrogate key (the _ID that is a unique integer value for each of your natural key values).

Generally, the surrogate key (assumed as integer) which you base your join upon will perform better than the natural key (assumed as string) - so you should use the surrogate key in the join conditions.

As for utility, I would include both the natural and surrogate key values in the select clause of the view.  This allows the view to be used with other tables / views where you can join on the surrogate key there as well.